# Optional binding with try? and as? still produces an optional type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have code for executing an `NSFetchRequest` and casting its result to an array of my custom data model type. Fetching may throw but I don't want to care about the error so I use `try?`, and I also use `as?` in casting. In Swift 2, this used to be just fine, but Swift 3 produces a double optional:

```
var expenses: [Expense]? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Expense.entityName)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateSpent >= %@ AND dateSpent <= %@", [self.startDate, self.endDate])

    // Returns [Expense]? because right side is [Expense]??
    if let expenses = try? App.mainQueueContext.fetch(request) as? [Expense],
        expenses?.isEmpty == false {
        return expenses
    }
    return nil
}
```

How can I rephrase the right side of my optional binding in `if let` so that its type will simply be an array `[Expense]`? I think it looks absurd that in the following boolean condition (which used to be a `where` clause), the array is still optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must wrap your `try?` call within parenthesis like this :

```
if let expenses = (try? App.mainQueueContext.fetch(request)) as? [Expense]
```

That's because `as?` has a higher precedence than `try?` (probably because `try?` can be applied to the whole expression).

Comment: Confirming that this works. What a tedious syntax though.

Answer (score 5):

@Fantattitude's answer gives what you want. But it takes me a while to go through the document to find out *why*. To long to be a comment, so here's the reference:

---

According to The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3) [Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) Chapter

> When the expression on the left hand side of a **binary operator** is marked with try, try?, or try!, that operator applies to the **whole** binary expression.

Firstly, I thought `as` may *not* be a binary operator, but in [Swift Standard Library Operators](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1851035-swift_standard_library_operators)

> `as`, `as?`, and `as!` are Infix operators operators

and in [Operator Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID380) chapter

> An **infix operator** is a *binary operator* that is written between its two operands, such as the familiar addition operator (+) in the expression 1 + 2.

Comment: Great investigation!

Comment: Hmm. I'm still a bit confused as to the technical details of this. If it is executing the code for App.mainQueueContext.fetch() and casting the result to [Expense] before it attempts to evaluate/apply the try? -- shouldn't this throw an error about running code that throws without any sort of error handling?

Comment: Don't have time to go through documentation, but I guess `as` has error/throw propagation.